# How to make an dropdown menu to sort data from an database

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am working on an application to use on an website. The application let you add job offers to a database to post it on the website and on social media. I have done a lot already but now I am trying to make an sort menu. In my database I have 1 row that is called Status. The Status is an enum with the data Open and Closed so I would like to have a sort option. I would like to sort on Open, Closed and all.

I already have a table and I would like to see the changes on that existed table if that is possible but I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody help me with this? I am using HTML, PHP and as database PHPMyAdmin. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 120px;
    }

    </style> 
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Jobs Overview (Admin)</h2>

  <form action="/action_page.php">    
  <select id="sorting">
    <option value="All" >All</option>
    <option value="Open">Open</option>
    <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
  </select>

<br><br>

<?php

include 'Connection.php';

echo "<table>";                                
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>" . "jid" . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . "role" . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . "type" . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . "availability" . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . "location" . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . "status" . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . "Verwijder?" . "</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

$select = "SELECT * FROM test";

$result = mysql_query($select);
if($result) {
}  else {
    echo "Error! <br>";
    echo mysql_error();
}

    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["jid"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href='jobsupdate.php?jid=" . $data["jid"] . "'>" . $data["role"] . " </a></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["type"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["availability"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["location"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["status"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href = 'jobsdelete.php?jid=" . $data["jid"] . "' onClick=\"return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je deze record wil verwijderen?');\"><center>Verwijder</center></a></td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>

    <br><br>

<a href="jobsadmin.php">Vacatures Toevoegen</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sort` by open means if sort by open then open jobs will be shown at the top ?

Comment: No I would like to have if i pick open it only shows the open jobs :) and not the closed once

Comment: check this . it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627922/how-to-search-value-from-input-by-mysqli-in-database/42628959#42628959

Comment: couldn't you just add the required sorting to the `SQL` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add HTML class to `open` and `closed` jobs.

```
 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $data["jid"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <a href='jobsupdate.php?jid=" . $data["jid"] . "'>" . $data["role"] . " </a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data["type"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data["availability"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data["location"] . "</td>";

        if ($data["status"] == 0) {
            echo "<td class='open'>" . $data["status"] . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td class='closed'>" . $data["status"] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<td> <a href = 'jobsdelete.php?jid=" . $data["jid"] . "' onClick=\"return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je deze record wil verwijderen?');\"><center>Verwijder</center></a></td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

After, this you have to write a jquery script to hide the jobs `.on` `change`.

```
$('#sorting').on('change', function(){
    var status = $('#sorting:selected').val();
    if (status == "Open") {
        $('.closed').hide();
    } else if (status == "Closed") {
        $('.open').hide();
    } else if (status == "All"){
        $('.closed').show();
        $('.open').show();
    }
});​
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `Ajax` post request on select change to get the records and put those records on success in your table.

More about how to do this with `Jquery` /  `Ajax` [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)

More about `Jquery` on change [here](https://api.jquery.com/change/)